# Send Data From RecyclerView To Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to send information from a Activity to a RecyclerView 
& I'm successful, but I'm failing to send information from RecyclerView to the second Fragment.
Let me be clearer :

```
DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements CallbackToActivity
```

**TO:**

```
RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>
```

**TO:**

```
GetDetailsFragment extends Fragment
```

I cant use Intent because the information from the Recycler is not sent to the Fragment
For the second time, I can't send the information using the bundle and getArguments to Fragment because it does not accept the use of Arguments in the Recycler.
I need to send the information like this so if you have any solution, please tell me

Answer (score 2):

Communication to fragment chould be done via activity.

1.send information back to activity.
2.call the method of the fragment from activity and pass the information received from recyclerview.